# Use pipes in css Angular 9

Tags: css, angular, pipe, ngx-translate

I want to put a text through the translate pipe, but the text is in the css in content.

```
.files:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "Drag your files here";
}
```

This does not work:

```
.files:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: {{'file.text' | translate}};
    }
```

Comment: I don't think so this will work, pipes required js context which you don't have in css files. I will suggest to add data attribute then use that data attribute in css.

Comment: As the data attribute is added, could you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this going to work.

By using pipe you can change the content in the HTML part, so just bind to some attribute in the DOM and try to read from there in css like this -

```
.files:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-lang)
}
```

For example you have DOM element, you need to add data attribute like mentioned below -

```
<p data-lang="en">Any content here </p>
```

Comment: Awesome! I've never thought of trying this approach with angular.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it? is that I have no idea of ​​css or attributes

Comment: Where i create data-before-content?